# How to return an error message when result is not found using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Hi guys I would like to display an error message when the result is not found and A user should be able to enter the number with or without spaces.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        var account = $("#number").val();
        if (account.length !== 10) {
            $("p").text("number is not valid").css("color","red");
        }
        if (account != "") {
            $.ajax({
                url: "profile.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    number:account,
                },
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#name").text(data.name);
                    $("#phone").text(data.phone);
                    $("#email").text(data.email);
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            $("p").text("Please Enter Phone Number");
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: just add if condition inside "success" function and check data variable. I think you can do that :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `error:` to do something when there is an error or exception from the URL.
You can edit your code as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        var account = $("#number").val();
        if (account.length !== 10) {
            $("p").text("number is not valid").css("color","red");
        }
        if (account != "") {
            $.ajax({
                url: "profile.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    number:account,
                },
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#name").text(data.name);
                    $("#phone").text(data.phone);
                    $("#email").text(data.email);
                }
                error: function(err) {
                    // do something or alert user
                    alert("Result is not found")
                }
            });
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks Its really helpfull

Comment: nice. please do accept answer if it was found working :)